# Using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, android, regex

I am having problems trying to use the regular expression that I used in JavaScript. On a web page, you may have:

```
<b>Renewal Date:</b> 03 May 2010</td>
```

I just want to be able to pull out the 03 May 2010, remembering that a webpage has more than just the above content. The way I currently perform this using JavaScript is:

```
DateStr = /<b>Renewal Date:<\/b>(.+?)<\/td>/.exec(returnedHTMLPage);
```

I tried to follow some tutorials on `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher` with no luck. I can't seem to be able to translate **(.+?)** into something they can understand??

thanks,

Noeneel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how regular expressions are used in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<b>Renewal Date:</b>(.+?)</td>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(returnedHTMLPage);

if (m.find()) // find the next match (and "generate the groups")
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // prints whatever the .+? expression matched.
```

There are other useful methods in the Matcher class, such as `m.matches()`. Have a look at [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Comment: To get a partial match, you need to use `find()` rather than `matches()`.  I've edited aioobe's answer to fix this.

Comment: @aiobe, thank you once again. Find() did the trick. Sorry for the newbie questions, have done lots of self taught JavaScript and am now trying to transition to JAVA.

Answer (score 4):

#### On `matches` vs `find`

The problem is that you used `matches` when you should've used `find`. From the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> - The `matches` method attempts to match the **entire input sequence** against the pattern.
> - The `find` method scans the input sequence **looking for the next** subsequence that matches the pattern.

Note that [`String.matches(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) also looks for a full match of the entire string. Unfortunately `String` does not provide a partial regex match, but you can always `s.matches(".*pattern.*")` instead.

---

#### On reluctant quantifier

Java understands `(.+?)` perfectly.

Here's a demonstration: you're given a string `s` that consists of a string `t` repeating at least twice. Find `t`.

```
System.out.println("hahahaha".replaceAll("^(.+)\\1+$", "($1)"));
// prints "(haha)" -- greedy takes longest possible

System.out.println("hahahaha".replaceAll("^(.+?)\\1+$", "($1)"));
// prints "(ha)" -- reluctant takes shortest possible
```

---

#### On escaping metacharacters

It should also be said that you have injected `\` into your regex (`"\\"` as Java string literal) unnecessarily.

```
        String regexDate = "<b>Expiry Date:<\\/b>(.+?)<\\/td>";
                                            ^^         ^^
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("<b>Expiry Date:<\\/b>");
                                                      ^^
```

`\` is used to escape regex metacharacters. A `/` is NOT a regex metacharacter.

#### See also

- [Regular expressions and escaping special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/regular-expressions-and-escaping-special-characters)

Comment: I only used it as it was suggested previously that I needed it. If I have just:
         String regexDate = "<b>Expiry Date:</b>(.+?)</td>";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexDate);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(returnedHTML);

            if (m.matches()) // check if it matches (and "generate the groups")
            {
                System.out.println("*******REGEX RESULT*******"); 
                System.out.println(m.group(1));      // prints whatever the .+? expression matched.
                System.out.println("*******REGEX RESULT*******"); 
            }
 it still fails

Comment: @bebeTech: use `if (m.find())` instead of `if (m.matches())` in this case. Look at the documentation to see difference.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: the problem is not the backslashes he introduced. They end up just quoting the / following them, so shouldn't mess with the results (although they are of course superfluous).

Comment: @wds: Ah, you're right. `"/".matches("\\/")` is `true`. Answer restructured.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so using aioobe's original suggestion (which i also tried earlier), I have:

```
String regexDate = "<b>Expiry Date:</b>(.+?)</td>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexDate);
Matcher m = p.matcher(returnedHTML);

if (m.matches()) // check if it matches (and "generate the groups")
{
  System.out.println("*******REGEX RESULT*******"); 
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // prints whatever the .+? expression matched.
  System.out.println("*******REGEX RESULT*******"); 
}
```

The IF statement must keep coming up FALSE as the *******REGEX RESULT******* is never outputted.

If anyone missed what I am trying to achieve, I am just wanting to get the date out. Amongst a html page is a date like `<b>Expiry Date:</b> 03 May 2010</td>` and I want the 03 May 2010.

Comment: Then change `if (m.maches())` to `if (m.find())`. As @polygenelubricants mentioned above!  @Jan even kindly updated my post to use `find()` instead of `matches()`.

Comment: Yes, 2 people with the correct answer but I can only tick one?

Answer (score 0):

`(.+?)` is an odd choice.  Try `( *[0-9]+ *[A-Za-z]+ *[0-9]+ *)` or just `([^<]+)` instead.

Comment: It works and validates as an ok syntax to use. Just can't get it to work with JAVA. I have it working fine with JS.